# Explain that the complex sine function is not bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

That is, for any positive constant $M$, there exists a $z$ such that $|\sin z|>M$.  Given $|\sin z|^2=(\sin x)^2+(\sinh y)^2$.

Comment: Do you know what the graph of $\sinh$ looks like?

Comment: yes, sinh is unbounded. so is it enough to prove sin^2+sinh^2 is unbounded?

Comment: @Amanda Yes, it's sufficient; you can take $x=0$, can't you?

Comment: Invocation of the hyperbolic sine is a regrettable red herring: use the definition of the complex sine function!

Comment: ..$\sin(z)$ is non-constant and entire.. Liouville's Theorem..?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin (-i n)=\frac {1}{2i}(e^n-e^{-n})$